# serre duality and logarithmic differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $D$ be a normal crossings divisor on some smooth projective variety $X$ (say over the complex numbers) and let $\Omega^p_X(\log D)$ be the sheaf of logarithmic $p$-forms. It is
$$
\Lambda^p \Omega^1_X(\log D)
$$

Can somebody explain why Serre duality gives
$$
H^q(X, \Omega^p_X(\log D)) \simeq H^{n-q}(X, \Omega^{n-p}_X(\log D)(-D))? 
$$

Thanks for your help

Comment: [Crossposted on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/135510/1916).